# What is difference between REST and SOAP Services

Tags: apex, apex-webservice

I am not able to get basic or the in depth difference, I think both are used for the same purpose so why there are two terms, I am very new to this so can anybody help me clear out the functionality difference between the both.

Comment: check few discussion [understanding-soap-and-rest-basics](http://blog.smartbear.com/apis/understanding-soap-and-rest-basics/) also [SOAP vs REST (differences)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19884975/4366769)

Comment: check this link:-http://www.javatpoint.com/soap-vs-rest-web-services   & http://spf13.com/post/soap-vs-rest

Answer (score 1):

Check this on trailhead module "Apex Integration Services" https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/apex_integration_services